# Indicator network doesn't reflect loss of connection

Tags: networking, network-manager, indicator

I've peculiar issue with network indicator. Occasionally, my wifi connection disappears , yet the indicator seems to suggest I am still connected.

[image]

How can I troubleshoot this ?